# Which files shoud I copy to my project to use ImageMagick? or How to compile ImageMagick with MinGW on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, imagemagick, mingw

My question might look a little simple because I am new with QT and C++ but I was struggling with this for a day, so I decided to ask someone for help. I am trying to use the `ImageMagick` library in my QT-MinGW C++ project to convert between different image types. I downloaded the source code from [here](https://imagemagick.org/www/script/advanced-unix-installation.php) and followed the described steps to build it:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Now I can use commands such as `convert`, `magick` and etc. in the command line, but How should I add the library to my QT project? There is no `.dll` and `\include` folder. Which files should I add to my project? Where is the library file?

> Note: I would like to use the library in the Windows environment. I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux to compile it.
>
> Note 2: I have tried to compile with MinGW MSYS on windows but I got thousands of warnings plus error : `c:\ImageMagic/MagickCore/nt-base.c:2774: undefined reference to SetDllDirectoryW' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: *** [MagickCore/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.la] Error 1`.

Desperately need for help.

Comment: I've never worked with imagemagic but the website seems to suggest using the magick++ library. https://imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php

Comment: If you are using WSL I assume your library is a .so or .a file and is compatible with the linux distribution you are using.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka In fact Magick++ is included as part of ImageMagick source. But I don't know how to include it in my project.

Comment: @drescherjm There is a `libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.a` file in `ImageMagick-7.0.10-29\Magick++\lib\.libs\` but is it the main library file? Which headers files should I use along with it?

Comment: The .a file is a static library and can be used for your linux development.

Comment: For windows binaries you will have to build with the compiler you are using or setup a cross build environment in your linux. I would expect building with mingw will be simpler than cross-compiling.

Comment: @drescherjm Can't I use `.a` file in a QT-MinGW project on windows? I am using MinGW on my windows project but my problem still stays the same. Where are library files and header files? There are different source folders in `ImageMagick` with both `.cpp`  and `.h` files. Which one of them should be added to my project?

Comment: No you can't use that .a file in windows.

Comment: @drescherjm Could you provide some more details? There isn't much documentation about how to build `ImageMagick` on internet ([Here](https://imagemagick.org/Magick++/Install.html)). I have MinGW MSYS installed on my windows but isn't it just a collection of UNIX tools? Has anyone used `Magick++` on windows?

Comment: Run the same build commands you did in your msys2. With that said maybe you can install using pacman.

Comment: ***Has anyone used Magick++ on windows?***  I have years ago but that was with Visual Studio which won't help you since you are using mingw.

Comment: Related to msys2: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-imagemagick](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-imagemagick)

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks but it throws errors : `c:\ImageMagic/MagickCore/nt-base.c:2774: undefined reference to SetDllDirectoryW'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [MagickCore/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.la] Error 1`.

Comment: I just tested installing in msys2 using pacman and the link above and it worked without any problem.`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-imagemagick` from a `msys2_shell.cmd` window.

Comment: @drescherjm Did you test it in a simple QT project? Which header files did you copy to your project? Can you leave your procedure as an answer?

Comment: I did not install qt-creator. I develop my Qt applications with CMake and Visual Studio 2019. I would expect not to copy any header files to your project instead  get qt-creator to use your msys2 install of mingw.

Comment: pacman installed the header files in the expected location of the msys2 tree in the include directory. For me that is `C:\msys64\mingw64\include\ImageMagick-7`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221273/discussion-between-newuser-and-drescherjm).

Answer (score 0):

If you have built ImageMagick with MinGW as both static and shared libraries you should have these `.a` files in the lib folder:

- libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.a
- libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.dll.a
- libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.a
- libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.dll.a
- libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.a
- libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.dll.a

and something like these `.dll` files in the bin folder:

- libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI-4.dll
- libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI-7.dll
- libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI-7.dll

If you don't have the `.dll.a` and `.dll` files then you don't have the shared build.

If you built ImageMagick yourself and the shared libraries are not built, it could be because the dependancies are also missing their shared libraries.

Comment: It failed when I used MinGW. How could you build that? Can you add your compiler version? Didn't you get any errors? Please describe the procedure.

Comment: I built all dependancies with both static and shared libraries, and then I build ImageMagick. You can imagine it's an immense task I can't just describe briefly.

Comment: When I try to build it I download it from [here](https://imagemagick.org/www/script/advanced-unix-installation.php) and use `./configure` and `make` on MSYS. It fails, please add some details in your answer.

Comment: I use this source file:
http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-7.0.10-29.tar.xz
and I configure like this: `./configure --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-zero-configuration --with-modules --without-x --with-gslib --without-perl --disable-openmp --enable-hdri --without-wmf CFLAGS="-fcommon" LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed -lws2_32 -Wl,--enable-auto-import"`